# Find element in a list

Tags: r, list

I have this character vector:

```
fruits <- c("melon", "grapefruit", "blueberry")
```

I also have this list:

```
list_fruits <- list(list(first = "orange", second =  NULL,  third = "pineapple"),
               list(first = "apple",  second = NULL, third = "melon"))

list_fruits

[[1]]
[[1]]$first
[1] "apple"

[[1]]$second
NULL

[[1]]$third
[1] "pineapple"


[[2]]
[[2]]$first
[1] "apple"

[[2]]$second
NULL

[[2]]$third
[1] "melon"
```

If any element of `fruits` is equal to the element any list `third` in `list_fruits`, I need the list `first` of `list_fruits` to be outputed as a character vector.

So if I ran the function on `list_fruits`, the output would be:

```
"apple"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner:

```
lapply(list_fruits[sapply(list_fruits, "[[", "third") %in% fruits], "[[", "first")
```

Comment: You can make anything a one-liner. It's how readable it is that really matters.

Comment: They are still fun though.

Comment: Then you might enjoy these: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf. Where readability is NOT a requirement. Not a lot of R programmers over there yet, which is a shame.

Answer (score 5):

Using `sapply`

```
sapply(list_fruits, function(X) if(X$third %in% fruits) X$first)

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "apple"
```

If the list gets very large, you may want to take another approach for efficiency - but that would depend on how the rest of the list looks.

Comment: Could wrap with `unlist` to get just one item. I'm sure you knew this but the OP might not.

Comment: Looks like you are matching the third fruit to the fruits while I am doing the other way around. Can lead to different results, which is up to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like that?

```
first_fruit <- vapply(list_fruits, `[[`, character(1L), "first")
third_fruit <- vapply(list_fruits, `[[`, character(1L), "third")

first_fruit[match(fruits, third_fruit)]
# [1] "apple" NA      NA     

as.character(na.omit(first_fruit[match(fruits, third_fruit)]))
# [1] "apple"
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform `list_fruits` structure before make it easier:

```
dat <- do.call(rbind,list_fruits)
dat[which(dat[,'third'] %in% fruits),'first']

$first
[1] "apple"
```